# Redirecting pages with confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I doing a little site for my web project, but I can't get the code to work. I have 4 "pages" (don't know what to call them) that I want to link to one another. You answer a question and an alert shows up redirecting you to the next page. I get the first link to work but not the other ones.

Here's my code:

```
<button data-href="../index.html" onclick="return confirm_alert(this);" class="knap3" >Nej</button>
```

This is what I used for the first link but it does not work when I have multiple of these in place. I tried giving them different tags/names but that didn't work.

```
function confirm_alert(element) {

redirect = confirm("confirmation for redirecting?");

if(redirect) {
  window.location = element.dataset.href
}
```

Edit: When I put multiple of these in my buttons did not work anymore(nothing happends when I clicked on them).

(English isn't my native language so sorry for all the spelling errors.)

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean?  What happened?  Did it redirect to the wrong page?  Not at all?

Comment: What code is on your subsequent pages? Would need to see it in action to  be able to tell you why it doesn't work. Do you have a live link for us to look at?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a link for you to look on sorry. Should I copy the code to the post?(It's not much at all)

Comment: @philtune what does code on a redirect page have anything to do with making the redirect work in the current page?

Answer (score 0):

here is code that works

```html
<button onclick="return confirm_alert('../index.html');" class="knap3" >Nej</button>
```

and

```js
function confirm_alert(next) {

var msg="confirmation for redirecting?";

if(confirm(msg)) {
   location.href=next;
}
}
```

here is a stand-alone page that works (i tested it), just save it to test.html and try it out. If this works, you can start building on it. if it does not, you have a separate issue that i cannot help with

```html
<button onclick="return confirm_alert('../index.html');" class="knap3" >Nej</button>

<script>

function confirm_alert(next) {

    var msg="confirmation for redirecting?";

    if(confirm(msg)) {
       location.href=next;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. Now nothing happens when I press the button. Any idea why?

Comment: i just edited the answer to add a stand-alone snippet that you can save to a file and try out. i tested it and it works (as it should). if this works for you and your page does not then you most likely have a typo in your script, missing bracket, open quote, or something like that.